# Solution of a functional integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I am trying to show the following integral has the following result

$$-\int \nabla^2\psi \text{d}  \psi^*=|\nabla\psi|^2$$

Going backwards I write

$$\frac{d}{d\psi^*}|\nabla\psi|^2=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dx}{d\psi^*}(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\cdot\frac{d\psi^*}{dx})=\nabla^2\psi$$

so I wonder, where is the minus sign disappearing\coming from?

Trying to integrate I don't have more luck: I would procede by parts so that
$$-\int \nabla^2\psi \text{d}  \psi^*=-\int\psi''d\psi^*=-\int\psi''\psi'^* dx= -\psi'\psi'^*+\int\psi'\psi''^*dx$$
but I don't know what to do with the expression

$$-\int\psi''\psi'^* dx-\int\psi'\psi''^*dx=2Re(\int\psi'\psi''^*dx)= -\psi'\psi'^*$$

Can someone help with the procedure to show the first equality is actually true?

Comment: Where are you integrating? What denotes $\psi^*?$

Comment: $\psi^*$ is the complex conjugate of $\psi$. $d\psi^*$ can be written as $d\psi^*=\frac{d\psi^*}{dx}dx=\psi'^*dx$.

Comment: $\psi$ is a distribution and it goes to zero at infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i am going to answer my own question; I hope it will be helpful for others .

Basically being $\psi$ a distribution it is defined as acting on a test function through a scalar product or analogously  integrated over its spatial variable $<\psi|\phi>=\int dr \psi\phi$.

Moreover one has to consider $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ independend one from the other so that

$$-\int d\psi^* \nabla^2\psi=-\psi^*\nabla^2\psi$$

Now this means

$$<-\psi^*|\nabla^2\psi>=-\int dr \psi^*\nabla^2\psi=\int dr \nabla\psi^*\nabla\psi=<\nabla\psi^*|\nabla\psi>=\int dr |\nabla\psi|^2$$

Where integration by parts has been used together with the fact that either $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ goes to zero at infinity or are at most subjected to periodic boundary conditions ( this cancels the other term arising from integration by parts )